# Data migration - SQL tables to Parquet framework

Tags: sql, migration, etl

I'm looking for a high level plan to perform ETL on calls that have been transcribed. The transcriptions are stored in a local software, so its on premise sql tables.  We are looking to move the speech transcriptions info into the data lake which is a parquet format table.
The data needs to be feed into the data lake on an hourly basis. 
My question is what are the data processes are required and the workflow in order to achieve the above reliably. How would the "Cron" Job work?.

Apologies that I could not provide more information.

Comment: You need to ask a much more focussed, detailed question for it to be answerable - at the moment is is much too broad for this forum. What is the ETL tool you are using, what is your target platform, what is the actual issue you are having, etc? BTW parquet is a file format,  it a table format